# Typescript - Type KeyValuePair<string, Date> is not assignable to type KeyValuePair<number, string>

Tags: typescript, generics

I am been shown the following error

```
Type 'KeyValuePair<string, Date>' is not assignable to type 'KeyValuePair<number, string>'. 
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

based on the following code

```
class KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> {
    constructor(public key: TKey, public value: TValue) {}
}

class KeyValuePairPrinter<T, U> {
    constructor(private pairs: KeyValuePair<T, U>[]) {}

    print() {
        for (let p of this.pairs) {
            console.log(`${p.key}: ${p.value}`);
        }
    }
}

let now = new Date(Date.now())
let pair1 = new KeyValuePair<number, string>(1, "First");
let pair2 = new KeyValuePair<string, Date>("Second", new Date(Date.now()));
let pair3 = new KeyValuePair<number, string>(3, "Third");

var printer = new KeyValuePairPrinter([
    pair1,
    pair2,
    pair3,
]);
printer.print();
```

as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

What could be causing this error?

Comment: `Pair2` is a different type than the others, while the constructor signature requires an array of the same type of objects.

Comment: @Alejandro Makes sense...

Comment: If you switch the signature in your class to <any, any> it should work. @Alejandro is correct that it takes in the first parameter and infers the type for the rest

Comment: If you use `<any, any>` you might as well not bother using typescript/generics at all

Comment: *What could be causing this error?* the error message seems to tell you what? `'KeyValuePair<string, Date>' is not assignable to type 'KeyValuePair<number, string>'`. i.e. `KeyValuePair<string, Date>` isn't the same type as `KeyValuePair<string, Date>`. It's not clear what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: @Liam Until Alejandro explained it, was not that obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, typescript infers the type of the generic argument based on what you first pass to the constructor.

```
let pair1 = new KeyValuePair<number, string>(1, "First");
let pair2 = new KeyValuePair<string, Date>("Second", new Date(Date.now()));
let pair3 = new KeyValuePair<number, string>(3, "Third");

var printer = new KeyValuePairPrinter([
    pair1, // KeyValuePair<number, string> => T = number, U = string
    pair2, // wrong type
    pair3, // correct type
]);
```

You can explicitly set the type of the generic arguments to circumvent typescripts inferred type:

```
var printer = new KeyValuePairPrinter<number | string, string | Date>([
    pair1, 
    pair2,
    pair3,
]);
```

Comment: this seems to make a mockery of using generics at all? why try and pass types when your going to make them so loose that those types become meaningless. `KeyValuePair` should probably just become `constructor(public key: any, public value: any)` without the generics as they're pretty pointless

Comment: @Liam In this scenario yes, but you can still use the class somewhere else where typescript correctly infers the types

Comment: IMO typescripts `Type | Type` syntax is stupid. It's either a strongly typed language or it's not. Trying to make it a little bit strongly typed seems dumb. If these things share properties, that's what interfaces are for, but hey that's just me :)

Comment: It should just use <any, any> in the constructor to avoid all this mess. Trying to be fancy with generics is not always the best solution to things.

Comment: @BenBrown `any` should be avoided since it actually breaks the whole concept of having types. It may look like a mess, but this still forces you to check and cast variables, whereas `any` just lets you write happy but ugly javascript.

Comment: @BenBrown there's no point in using generics at all if your not going to restrict the types. Rather than using `KeyValuePair<any, any>` it should be `KeyValuePair` as these are essentially identical and involve less setup. Again, IMO you should never use `any` in typescript; again, you're either using types (typescript) or you not (javascript). There's no point being half hearted about it.